# Выделение user space памяти из Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, c, память, kernel

Всем привет. Можно ли выделить область памяти пользовательского пространства и вернуть указатель на него из модуля ядра Linux? Я знаю, что пользовательские процессы используют виртуальную память и виртуальное адресное пространство, для выделения смежной виртуальной памяти можно использовать vmalloc, но будет ли она доступна пользовательскому процессу? Так же можно использовать kmalloc с флагом GFP_USER, но будет ли эта память доступна пользовательскому процессу?
Так же я не уверен, не приведет ли доступ по адресам, указывающим на выделенную в другом процессе память, к segmentation fault. Буду благодарен тому, кто прольет свет на эти вопросы. Спасибо.

Comment: конкретики ради, что именно ты пытаешься сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Можно ли выделить область памяти пользовательского пространства и
> вернуть указатель на него из модуля ядра Linux?

Это довольно странная идея... А если при работающем приложении модуль будет выгружен из памяти ядра - тогда что произойдёт?

На самом деле, доступ к памяти пользователя из ядра возникает только в трёх ситуациях:

1. Выполняется операция ввода в буфер пользователя
2. Выполняется операция вывода из буфера пользователя
3. Выполняется обработка вызова *ioctl()* в котором третий аргумент - указатель на буфер пользователя.

При всех трёх вариантах надобности **выделить** память пользователю из ядра просто не возникает. Для передачи данных при этом используются вызовы API ядра:

```
copy_to_user()
copy_from_user()
```

Поченму это так, почитатйте вот здесь:

https://coderoad.ru/12666493/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-copy_to_user-copy_from_user-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%BA

Иногда, очень редко, возникает реальная ситуация, когда ядру необходимо вернуть пользователю заранее неизвестный объём памяти с данными. Широко известный пример - опрос пользователем свойств сетевых интерфейсов системы.

Пользователь заранее не знает, **сколько** интерфейсов в системе и не может заранее выделить достаточную память. Поэтому приходится использовать такой довольно запутанный механизм:

1. Прикладная программа организует цикл вызова *ioctl()* начиная от буфера размером в один элемент.
2. Ядро отвечает, что памяти недостаточно
3. Прикладная программа выделяет больший буфер
4. Выполняется вызов *ioctl()* с новым размером буфера

И так далее, пока *ioctl()* не завершится с нулевым кодом ошибки.

Comment: Воу, спасибо за такой развернутый ответ!